# The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: php, paypal

I have read other posts on the very same subject but I am pretty sure I have not fallen foul of the issues of those posts. This is really frustrating me now so any help or advice would be appreciated.

I am building the following array to be sent in the SetExpressCheckout call but upon each submission i get "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts " but I dont understand how!!

```
[METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
[USER] => myusername
[PWD] => 1398341028
[SIGNATURE] => xxxsignaturexxx
[VERSION] => 85.0
[RETURNURL] => http://www.mysite.dev/payment/process
[CANCELURL] => http://www.mysite.dev/payment/cancelled
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => SALE
[NOSHIPPING] => 0
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 189.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 189.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
[LOCALECODE] => GB
[ALLOWNOTE] => 1
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Website Order
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => 28424747
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 189.00
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
```

Many Thanks for reading.
Kris

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and tested your call using a test account and initially it gave a similar error to what you described. I did get it to work with the only modifications I made being the format and spacing of the call.

This is the call I submitted and got a successful response, note I did have to change the user, pwd, signature, version, returnrul, and cancelurl to be able to test it:

```
USER=chad_1311276857_biz_api1.x.com 
PWD=NGAEWP367NNSDXP2 
SIGNATURE=Aef0iZ4csmtdchFhBLFKNKS88OSVA0f08rNWMEUk1J-tsdbDOFq0JpNi 
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout 
VERSION=113.0 
RETURNURL=http://ccaples.com/index.php/api-s/paypal-nvp/nvp-quick-test 
CANCELURL=http://ccaples.com/index.php/api-s/paypal-nvp/nvp-quick-test 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE 
NOSHIPPING=0 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=189.00 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=189.00 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=0 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=0 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=GBP 
LOCALECODE=GB 
ALLOWNOTE=1 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Website Order 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=28424747 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=189.00 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
```